# How could I make someone walk in place?

Tags: hardware, virtual-reality

I'm working on a serious project and I really need help.

I'm working on a virtual reality First-Person-Shooter game. The problem is that I want to make the player (a real person) walk in place (about only 3 square meters) while playing, and give him the feel of walking, strafing and running, and at the same time detect the distance he should have moved in both axis if he wasn't playing (in real life).

I thought of making him wear shoes containing spheres at the bottom, or making them walk on sliding spheres, but all those are dumb ideas! Any good ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ideas don't just sound dumb, they also sound quite dangerous. Remember that a player with a VR headset can not see anything of their *real* surrounding, which greatly increases risk of injury. So safety always needs to be a concern.

What you need (or rather your players need) is an [omni-directional threadmill](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmm4qYqhw0I).

The floor of this contraption can move in any direction.

The device detects when the user walks into one direction, and then the threadmill moves them into the opposite direction to bring them back into the center.

The ring on waist height makes sure the player can not fall off the device.

[The product from that video](http://www.virtuix.com/products/) (with which I have no affiliation) is not on the market yet, but with a price tag of $700 (just the threadmill without the headset and computer) it seems quite affordable... if it will get on the market and is not just vaporware.

Comment: I think the description of how the "treadmill" works is not correct for the Virtuix Omni. The player wears special shoes which glide on the surface of the Omni. It feels like you are walking but you stay in position and your feet move in the same motion as walking. If I remember it correctly from a presentation a few years ago the shoes move along small notches. The video looks like this hasn't changed.